# how to get last modified filename using boto3 from s3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to get the last modified file from an Amazon S3 directory.
I tried to only print that file's date only now, but I am getting the error:

> TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3',aws_access_key_id='demo', aws_secret_access_key='demo')

my_bucket = s3.Bucket('demo')

for file in my_bucket.objects.all():
    # print(file.key)
    print(max(file.last_modified))
```

Comment: It's the `max()` function which might be causing the issue. What do you want to achieve by using max on a `datetime` object.

Comment: i am new to boto3 and also for the s3 i want to get the last modified file. i just tried that max() function, can you suggest me any other way how to get that file.

Comment: use **max(my_bucket.objects.all(), key=lambda x: x.last_modified))** or so

Comment: in the directory there are more than 30k .csv files. i just want the last modified filename. @AnkitJaiswal

Comment: If there is no way to sort by last_modified field in boto library, you'll need to iterate and find out the file with max last_modified value, similar to what @kofemann has suggested.

Comment: ok i got this output `s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='demo', key='ETFHoldingData/kraneshares/KCCB-KCCB-10-23-2018.xls')` , how can i print this key(filename) only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There you have a simple snippet. In short you have to iterate over files to find the last modified date in all files. Then you have print files with this date (might be more than one).

```
from datetime import datetime

import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3',aws_access_key_id='demo', aws_secret_access_key='demo')

my_bucket = s3.Bucket('demo')

last_modified_date = datetime(1939, 9, 1).replace(tzinfo=None)
for file in my_bucket.objects.all():
    file_date = file.last_modified.replace(tzinfo=None)
    if last_modified_date < file_date:
        last_modified_date = file_date

print(last_modified_date)

# you can have more than one file with this date, so you must iterate again
for file in my_bucket.objects.all():
    if file.last_modified.replace(tzinfo=None) == last_modified_date:
        print(file.key)
        print(last_modified_date)
```

Comment: I know it's not python way. To make it short, then use *lambda* function in Python

Comment: i am getting this `TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.datetime) `

Comment: yes with the lambda i got the result but just to try i had used your code. thank for the help man can you tell me how to resolve this i hade change vale of last_modfied_date to datetime.datetime.now()

Answer (score 0):

you will get last modified filename and folder names using boto3 from s3

reference for function tools and reduce - [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reduce-in-python/)

```
from functools import reduce
import boto3
# replace with your access key and secret key

#s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id='demo', aws_secret_access_key='demo')

import boto3
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='demo', aws_secret_access_key='demo')
response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='bucket_name', Prefix='subfolder name')
#Replace with your bucket name and subfolder name
all = response['Contents']        
latest = max(all, key=lambda x: x['LastModified'])
print(latest)
#print(latest.values())
list(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, latest.items()))
a = list(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, latest.items()))
print(a[1])
```

output

```
# if you have one sub folder, you will get output in this below format
subfolder/filename.format
# if you having more than one sub folders, you will get output in this below format
subfolder1/subfolder2/filename.format
```

you need to get last modified folders and filed name based on your bucket name

Then refer this below changes

```
#instead of this code
response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='bucket_name', Prefix='subfolder name')
#remove prefix and subfolder name
response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='bucket_name') 
#Replace with you bucket name
```